# Debugging in Google App Engine Python Sandbox

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine, sandbox

I am just starting to use Python GAE in Windows 7.
Based on my observations, it seems like changes that I make to the python scripts in my
local app engine directory do not show up when I launch the code to my 'localhost:XXXX' sandbox.

For example, I'll import one of my scripts and invoke some functions, and I get the error below.

The weird thing about this error is that the 'exec()' call is no longer at line 99 in the copy of 'main.py' that I have been revising.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/[app name]/1.354953192642593048/main.py", line 99, in post
    exec(cmd, safe_globals)
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
NameError: name 'myFunction' is not defined
```

I guess my questions are:

1) What/where is '/base/data/home/apps/[app name]/1.354953192642593048/main.py'? Is this where they compile and run everything?

2) How can I 'rebuild' the local copy of my app folder such that the revisions I make are reflected in the sandbox?

Sorry for this relatively vague question. If somebody could explain how the sandbox is setup so I can figure out how to properly do debugging I would appreciate it.

---

**UPDATE:**

Never figured out how / why this error occurred. The output from that app engine directory was totally static no matter what kind of changes I tried to make, so I just deleted the folder and opened a new one. With this new folder (same exact contents, including app.yaml and main.py), I can make changes on the fly and my local debugger reflects those changes. 


 No longer a pressing issue, but if anybody has an idea as to how / why this error was occuring, I would be interested to hear it. As suggested in the comments below, the path provided in the error message is highly indicative of the workings of some remote base/ directory, even though I have been running everything on my localhost:[Port#] without any app deployment.

Comment: did you try looking at any of: (1) C:\base\...\main.py OR (2) C:\path\to\GAE\folder\base\...\main.py OR (3) C:\path\to\homefolder\base\...\main.py? You might at least be able to see it there... on linux GAE, it autoupdates everything, so it at least *should* do that.  Also, I know this is super basic, but are you sure you saved the file? Did you check to see if you are using the newest version? uninstall/reinstall GAE?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the advice. I wasn't able to find such a path on my system. As for the GAE folder itself, I have been revising and saving my revisions on the main.py in that folder. I have also tried changing localhost ports, still receiving the same error. When you say newest version, do you mean of the launcher? I just installed it today, so I hope that is not the problem. This is really puzzling to me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're running it locally?  The traceback looks like it's from the app server.  The  '`/base/data/home/apps/[app name]/1.354953192642593048/main.py`' looks like the path to your application on Google's app server, not a Windows file path.

Comment: Exactly, no such path exists on my computer, so this is part of my confusion. I am definitely running it locally because I am just using the launcher and I haven't deployed anything yet.

Comment: Jacob is right - that stack trace is definitely from production, not from your local machine.